# Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0 at <Jasmine>

Tags: angular, typescript, karma-jasmine

I have this error 'SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0', what is the best way for to mock cookieService?

My spec file:

```
import { CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA } from "@angular/core";
import { HttpClientTestingModule, HttpTestingController } from '@angular/common/http/testing';
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed } from "@angular/core/testing";
import { FilterComponent } from "./filter.component";
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';
import { CookieModule, CookieService } from 'ngx-cookie';
import { Api } from '../../services/api.service';

describe('filter Component', () => {
  let component: FilterComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<FilterComponent>;
  let httpMock: HttpTestingController;
  let cookieService: CookieService;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        imports: [
            HttpClientTestingModule,
            RouterTestingModule,
            CookieModule.forRoot()
        ],
        declarations: [
            FilterComponent,
        ],
        providers: [
          Api,
          CookieService,
        ],
        schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]
    }).compileComponents();
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(FilterComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    service = TestBed.inject(Api);
    httpMock = TestBed.inject(HttpTestingController);
    cookieService = TestBed.inject(CookieService);
    cookieService.put('user', user.username);
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

});
```

My typescript file (Constructor) in this code I call the function cookie.get:

```
constructor(
        private api: Api,
        private cookie: CookieService,
    ) {
        this.user = JSON.parse(this.cookie.get('user'));
    }
```

Comment: Is `user.username` a valid JSON string? It's likely `undefined`, so you're trying to parse the string `"undefined"` as JSON, and that's not valid JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolution so to solve that, just check if the string your are trying to parse is empty/null or not. if is not empty/null you can parse that string.

```
if (yourValue != null) {
   output = JSON.parse(yourValue);
}
```

Comment: Can be simplified to just `if (yourValue) { // rest of the code // }`